# Jquery append creating issues

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, node.js

Using append my innerdiv is attaching only one WHEAT-COLORED-BOX*; while using appendTo my innerdiv is attaching all the required number of WHEAT-COLORED-BOXES. Thus, for my case **appendto** is giving right result while **append** fails to do so!

```js
$(()=>{

    $('button').click(function appendizing(){
        for(let i=1; i<=9; ++i)
             $('<div></div>').addClass('box').css("backgroundColor", "wheat").appendTo('.container');
    });

});
```

```css
.container{
    font-size: 0px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}

.box{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>

<button>appendDiv</button>
```

**now look at this APPEND method usage** ->

```js
$(()=>{

    $('button').click(function appendizing(){
    for(let i=1; i<=9; ++i)
$('.container').append('<div</div>').addClass('box').css("backgroundColor", "wheat");
    });

});
```

```css
.container{
    font-size: 0px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}

.box{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>

    <button>appendDiv</button>
```

What is the reason for this. Kindly explain...

Comment: the issue is in your HTML that your are going to append
you did not close the div tag proper 
$('.container').append('<div</div>').addClass('box').css("backgroundColor", "wheat");

Replace below line with your code
$('.container').append('<div></div>').addClass('box').css("backgroundColor", "wheat");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This

```js
$(()=>{

    $('button').click(function appendizing(){
    for(let i=1; i<=9; ++i)
$('.container').append($('<div></div>').addClass('box').css("backgroundColor", "wheat"));
    });

});
```

```css
.container{
    font-size: 0px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}

.box{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>

    <button>appendDiv</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You forgot to close the **div** tag
2. You are adding class and style to the **container**, not to the appending **div**-s. You can specify it inline on append or create element and then append it.

```js
$(()=>{

    $('button').click(function appendizing(){
    for(let i=1; i<=9; ++i)
$('.container').append('<div class="box" style="background-color: wheat;"></div>');
    });

});
```

```css
.container{
    font-size: 0px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}

.box{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>

    <button>appendDiv</button>
```